# how can i get properly expressed answer(only expressed with constants) in ti-nspire cas(system of linear equations)

Tags: ti-nspire

I'm struggling with ti linear equation solving. I want to solve system of equations of two variables(i,v).
following is two equations.

**ai=v+iq**

**v=(i-1-bv)p**

When I use ti-nspire cas function 'solve' answer i=,v= still contains i and v. But I want to express them in unknown constants(a,b,p,q) only. How can I do that??

I tried to express them in other ways, But it doesn't work.

And some times answer of system of equation contains expression like'x=c5'. I wonder What c5 is meaning.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to use explicit mulitplication:

[image]]